# Create serial number with 8 length digits

Tags: php

i want to create a format like this: 0000-0000. I already i have the unique number, but i need to merge it with my format type.

```
$my_id_unique = '60';

//some function....

//IT SHOULD OUTPUT LIKE THIS
$create_serial = '0000-0060';
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: I tried like (00000000+60) and i ll use split function. but dose not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$x = sprintf("%08d",$my_id_unique);
$create_serial = substr($x,0,4).'-'.substr($x,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

With oneliner:

```
$create_serial = implode('-', str_split(sprintf('%08d', $my_id_unique), 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use [str_pad](https://www.php.net/str_pad):

```
echo str_pad('60', 9, '0000-0000', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```